# How to send an Audio for Dialogflow using C# library - DetectIntent

Tags: c#, audio, dialogflow-es, naudio

I am using the Dialogflow C# Library **Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2** to communicate with my Dialogflow Agent.

Everything works find when sending **Text** using the **DetectIntentAsync()**

My issue is when sending an **AUDIO** and more precisely with this Format: **.AAC**

To be able to send an **audio** using **DetectIntentAsync**() we need to create a **DetectIntentRequest** like below

```cs
 DetectIntentRequest detectIntentRequest = new DetectIntentRequest
            {
                InputAudio = **HERE WHERE I HAVE AN ISSUE**,
                QueryInput = queryInput,
                Session = "projects/" + _sessionName.ProjectId + "/agent/sessions/" + _sessionName.SessionId
            };
```

Where the **QueryInput** is configured with **AudioConfig** like below

```cs
            QueryInput queryInput = new QueryInput
            {
                AudioConfig = audioConfig,
            };
```

Where the **AudioConfig** is configured like below

```cs
   var audioConfig= new InputAudioConfig
            {
                AudioEncoding = **HAVING ISSUE HERE ON HOW TO CHOOSE THE CORRECT ENCODING**,
                LanguageCode = "en-US",
                ModelVariant = SpeechModelVariant.Unspecified,
                SampleRateHertz = **HAVING ISSUE HERE ON HOW TO CHOOSE THE CORRECT SAMPLE RATE HERTZ**,
            };
```

**PROBLEM**

- How to figure out what **SampleRateHertz** to choose?
- How to figure out what **AudioEncoding** to choose?
- How to provide the correct **Protobuf.ByteString** to **InputAudio**?
- What if i want to use other formats than .AAC, how to automatically provide the needed info? 

  **WHAT I TESTED**

I got the **byte[]** from a URL

```cs
// THE AUDIO IS A .AAC FILE
string audio = "https://cdn.fbsbx.com/v/t59.3654-21/72342591_3243833722299817_3308062589669343232_n.aac/audioclip-1575911942672-2279.aac?_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=heP60KND_DMAQl5-tE77rKNtUzHw_aILXdKfPPejdr7YVqzbYLQRv9BWA&_nc_ht=cdn.fbsbx.com&oh=1c4dbf0a64e0d1fb057b79354c17ca1c&oe=5DF17429";
byte[] audioBytes;
            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                audioBytes = webClient.DownloadData(audio);
            }
```

Then I added that into the **DetectIntentRequest** like below

```cs
DetectIntentRequest detectIntentRequest = new DetectIntentRequest
            {
                InputAudio = Google.Protobuf.ByteString.CopyFrom(audioBytes),
                QueryInput = queryInput,
                Session = "projects/" + _sessionName.ProjectId + "/agent/sessions/" + _sessionName.SessionId
            };
```

If I do not specify the **SampleRateHertz** i get the following error:

Error: **"{"Status(StatusCode=InvalidArgument, Detail=\"Invalid input audio or config. Unable to calculate audio duration. Possibly no audio data sent.\")"} "**

I **stopped** getting the error when **I Specified a SampleRateHertz** value but this is the response I keep getting no matter what values I use in the AudioEncoding and SampleRateHertz:

Response:  **{{ "languageCode": "en" }}**

Everything else in the **DetectIntentResponse is null**

Guidance/Help is appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who face the .AAC issue with dialogflow, I managed to get it working like below:

```cs
 DetectIntentResponse response = new DetectIntentResponse();
            var queryAudio = new InputAudioConfig
            {
                LanguageCode = LanguageCode,
                ModelVariant = SpeechModelVariant.Unspecified,
            };

            QueryInput queryInput = new QueryInput
            {
                AudioConfig = queryAudio,
            };

                var filename = "fileName".wav";
                // userAudioInput is the .AAC string URL 
                // creating and saving the wav format from AAC
                using (var reader = new MediaFoundationReader(userAudioInput))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(path + "/" + filename, reader);
                }
                // Reading the previously saved wav file
                byte[] inputAudio = File.ReadAllBytes(path + "/" + filename);

                DetectIntentRequest detectIntentRequest = new DetectIntentRequest
                {
                    //InputAudio = Google.Protobuf.ByteString.CopyFrom(ReadFully(outputStreamMono)),
                    InputAudio = Google.Protobuf.ByteString.CopyFrom(inputAudio),
                    QueryInput = queryInput,
                    Session = "projects/" + _sessionName.ProjectId + "/agent/sessions/" + _sessionName.SessionId
                };

                // Make the request
                response = await _sessionsClient.DetectIntentAsync(detectIntentRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

The **AAC** codec is **not supported** by DialogFlow at this time. You can find a list of supported formats in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding#audio-encodings). If you can not change the input file, you'll have to transcode it (preferably using a library, e.g. [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio)). The correct value to enter for `AudioEncoding` can be found in the [API reference](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2/api/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2.AudioEncoding.html).

The same page also has information on which [sample rates to use](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#sample-rates). These depend on the input supplied, so for the standard wave container formats (FLAC and WAV) they are included in the file and therefore optional. For other files, the value **must match the sampling rate of the audio** within it and is usually included in the file header. Again, reading it by hand for every format is painful, so either use a library or make sure that all input files have the same sampling rate and hard-code it.